# Cleaner jQuery code - nested div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I guys, I am using [wenzhixin multiple select plugin](https://github.com/wenzhixin/multiple-select/) for multiselect dropdown.

The HTML Looks like this:

```
<div class="fields">
     <select multiple="multiple" id="dd-items" class="multi-select-long" name="items" style="display: none;">
        <option value="1">Pen</option>
        <option value="2">Book</option>
        <option value="9">Pencils</option>
        <option value="4">Text books</option>
        <option value="8">Sharpners</option>
        <option value="5">Erasers</option>
        <option value="7">Colors</option>
    </select>
    <div class="ms-parent">
        <button class="ms-choice" type="button" style="width: 100%;">
            <span class="placeholder" style="width: 498px;">Select items</span>
            <div class="open"></div>
        </button>
        <div class="ms-drop" style="width: 100%; display: block;">
            <ul style="max-height: 150px;">
                <li>
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="selectAll"> [All items]
                    </label>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="selectItem"> Pen
                    </label>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" value="2" name="selectItem"> Book
                    </label>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" value="9" name="selectItem"> Pencils
                    </label>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" value="4" name="selectItem"> Text books
                    </label>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" value="8" name="selectItem"> Sharpners
                    </label>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" value="5" name="selectItem"> Erasers
                    </label>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" value="7" name="selectItem"> Colors
                    </label>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I call the multiselect function like this:

```
jQuery('#dd-items').multipleSelect({
    selectAllText : 'All items',
    placeholder : 'Select item',
    maxHeight: 150,

    onCheckAll: function() {
        jQuery('#dd-items').siblings().find('.ms-choice').find('span').text('All items') ;
        jQuery('#dd-items').siblings().find('.ms-drop').find("input[type='checkbox'][name='selectItem']").prop('disabled',true);
    },
    onUncheckAll: function() {
        jQuery('#dd-items').siblings().find('.ms-drop').find("input[type='checkbox'][name='selectItem']").prop('disabled',false);
    },
    onClick: function(view) {
        if(jQuery('#dd-items').siblings().find('.ms-drop').find("input[type='checkbox'][name='selectItem']:checked").length == jQuery('#dd-items').siblings().find('.ms-drop').find("input[type='checkbox'][name='selectItem']").length)
        {
            jQuery('#dd-items').multipleSelect("checkAll");
        }
    }

});
```

Now as you can see above Even though the code works fine but the code for OnCheckAll, OnUncheckAll and onClick is a bit messy.

Can someone please suggest a cleaner way to do this??

P.S. I have more than one multi select dropdown on the page. `<div class="ms-parent">` is generated by the plugin.

Comment: This is actually off-topic for Stack Overflow, try http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @DanielImms I am sorry. I think some misunderstsnding here. I have written the code you see in these function OnCheckAll, OnUncheckAll and onClick and is not the plugin code. So using sibilings().find I find this a bit messy. so want to optimise it. Can you pls help?

Comment: @SalmanA thanks for that. But is there any way to omit even the siblings part? I just feel its messy.

Comment: Use pure CSS selectors e.g. `$("#dd-items ~ * .ms-choice span")` (optimize depending on your markup)

Comment: @SalmanA but it isn't the `#dd-items` I want to select but the adjacent div to this. So will it be possible by using pure css selectors?

Comment: The `~/+` selector selects siblings (`~` selects all next, `+` selects adjacent next). See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Revised version of your code:

```
jQuery('#dd-items').multipleSelect({
    selectAllText: 'All items',
    placeholder: 'Select item',
    maxHeight: 150,
    onCheckAll: function () {
        jQuery('#dd-items ~ div span').text('All items');
        jQuery('#dd-items ~ div input[name=selectItem]').prop('disabled', true);
    },
    onUncheckAll: function () {
        jQuery('#dd-items ~ div input[name=selectItem]').prop('disabled', false);
    },
    onClick: function (view) {
        if (jQuery('#dd-items ~ div input[name=selectItem]:not(:checked)').length === 0) {
            jQuery('#dd-items').multipleSelect("checkAll");
        }
    }
});
```

Basically I have replaced all `.siblings().find()` with `~ div element`. The `~` selector is a CSS selector so it should be faster. I have tried to use shortest possible selectors (e.g. `~ div span` instead of `~ .ms-parent .ms-choice span.placeholder`). Also I have inverted the `if` condition. [Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/5vmjj/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dhana36/y6XgY/174/)

```
jQuery('#dd-items').multipleSelect({
    selectAllText : 'All items',
    placeholder : 'Select item',
    filter: true,
    maxHeight: 150,

    onCheckAll: function() {
        jQuery('#dd-items').multipleSelect("checkAll");
    },
    onUncheckAll: function() {
        jQuery('#dd-items').multipleSelect("uncheckAll");
    },
    onClick: function(view) {
        //jQuery('#dd-items').multipleSelect("checkAll");
    }

});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it won't help as I want to disable all the checkboxes if the 1st checkbox i.e. 'All items' is checked which is not inbuilt.

Comment: this doesn't work as jQuery('input[type=checkbox]') will select all the checkboxes on the webpage which I don't want as I have more than one multiple select dropdown.